# Spark job throws “org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]”

Tags: apache-spark

I am running Spark on AWS EMR, but the spark job sometimes throws org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]”

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing `spark.shuffle.io.connectionTimeout` interval. 600 seconds value resolved the issue for me.

This is network issue among nodes. Increase it as per requirements.